# Place time displayed in the beginning of modeline

Tags: mode-line

I installed doom-emacs and modeline displayed as

[image]

How could I place the time `10:55 AM` in the beginning, since if more windows are opened and arranged horizontally, the directory names are long enough to push "displayed time" out of view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can re-define the main mode line with [`doom-modeline-def-modeline`](https://github.com/seagle0128/doom-modeline/blob/6fcf65d2ef85202ba559c91f99ab1cf540d2fbd4/doom-modeline-core.el#L630).
The first argument is the mode line type, the second argument is the left-hand segment list, and the third argument is the right-hand segment list.

Shift the `misc-info` entry from the right-hand segment list to the beginning of the left-hand segment list.

With the [current version of the main mode line](https://github.com/seagle0128/doom-modeline/blob/6fcf65d2ef85202ba559c91f99ab1cf540d2fbd4/doom-modeline.el#L92-L94) you get after this modification:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "doom-modeline"
  (doom-modeline-def-modeline 'main
  '(misc-info bar workspace-name window-number modals matches buffer-info remote-host buffer-position word-count parrot selection-info)
  '(objed-state persp-name battery grip irc mu4e gnus github debug lsp minor-modes input-method indent-info buffer-encoding major-mode process vcs checker)))
```

Tested with emacs 26.3 and `doom-modeline-20200110.440`.

Disclaimer: I do not use `doom-modeline`. That is just what I got in a couple of minutes. Maybe, there is another way to re-configure `doom-modeline`.

Comment: I found the implicit "take-a-look-at-the-source" above to be on the money -- the doom-modeline source is pretty readable and informative.